# custom .desktop entry to launch Minecraft not working

Tags: java, minecraft, .desktop, elementary

I have made a Minecraft.desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications/ that reads as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Minecraft
Comment=Play this game in OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime
Exec=minecraft
Terminal=false
Icon=minecraft
Type=Application
Categories=Game;
```

and my "minecraft" script reads:

```
java -jar ~/Desktop/Minecraft.jar
```

I can enter `java -jar ~/Desktop/Minecraft.jar` into the teminal and minecraft will start.  I can also enter `minecraft` into the terminal and the script will run and the game will start.  However, the icon will not actually appear to do anything when I click it with this configuration.  I tried first with the Exec line as `Exec=java -jar ~/Desktop/Minecraft.jar`, but that didn't work, so I tried the script.   I just don't know why nothing seems to happen when I use the launcher icon??

any thought on this issue? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my problem after a little more experimenting:

I needed the script in a default PATH area, because it seems that `.bashrc` does not run before the `.desktop` Exec occurs.  So what this means is that instead of having my `minecraft` script in my `~/Desktop/scripts` folder (which is added to my path in `.bashrc`), I placed the script in `/usr/local/sbin`.

So I hope this might help anyone else wanting to make an awesome Minecraft icon!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the path where ever you have created this .desktop file open terminal to that path and type

```
 sudo desktop-file-install Minecraft.desktop
```

This will add entry to the launcher.Find it use it .